# Double number formatting in java

Tags: java, string, formatting

I am working on a calculator program in Java and I need to display a number with no more than 15 digits in length (decimal point included).

I've tried to format this number using `String.format("%g", myDouble)`, also with `%f`, but can't get the result I'm looking for.

The thing is that I need the number:

- to be displayed as scientific notation if it has more than 15 digits,
- or display it without rounding it if it has less than 15 digits.

Also, I do not want any fixed number of digits before or after the decimal point.

Any suggestions?

This is the code snipet where my number gets displayed:

```
if (("" + myDouble).length() > 15) {
    screen.setText(String.format("%g", myDouble));
} else {
    screen.setText("" + myDouble);
}
```

One problem is that when the `else` clause is executed, sometimes the numbers get displayed as `9.0000E7`, which is not favorable and is different from the `String.format("%g", myDouble)` scientific notation which looks more like `9.000e+7`.

Comment: Have you tried DecimalFormat class? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html  (bottom of the page)

Comment: Can you please clarify: what is the rounding behavior you are wanting for the scientific notation? (Also supposed to be limited to 15 digits...?)

Comment: Hint:  saying that `n` "has more than 15 digits" is the same as saying `Math.abs(n) >= 1000000000000000.0`.

Comment: @jameslarge Maybe. That depends on what the OP means by "digits". Personally I now think the OP needs to spend time clarifying exactly the behavior they want because it's actually pretty vague.

Comment: @Radiodef typical behavior for a "scientific" pocket calculator with a fixed-width display when in "floating point mode" or in "fixed decimal mode" is to fall back to "scientific mode" when there's no room to show all of the digits left of the decimal point.  They also typically reserve one display column for the sign, so the switch effectively happens when the absolute value of the result is greater than or equal to 10^w where w is 8 or 10 or 12 or however many digits the calculator is able to display.

Comment: @jameslarge The OP is shown to use `myDouble.length()` as a measure, which includes e.g. `123456789.123456789` which your abs test would fail. Again...can't make assumptions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be close to what you're asking for:

```
static String format(double n) {
    if(Double.isInfinite(n) || Double.isNaN(n))
        return Double.toString(n);
    String result = BigDecimal.valueOf(n).toPlainString();
    if(result.length() > 15)
        result = String.format("%.15e", n);
    return result;
}
```

Since your requirement is that the decimal places *aren't* fixed, I don't really see a way to do it with a formatter exclusively.

If you want a particular number of digits for the scientific notation, then you can use a format like `"%.15e"` where `15` is the number of decimal digits you want.

Or possibly you want something like:

```
if(result.length() > 15)
    result = new DecimalFormat("0.###############E0").format(n);
```

But if you're trying to "block align" to some maximum, then things get complicated because the number of fractional digits depends on the number of digits in the exponent.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `NumberFormat` object. See [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) for details.

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();
if (("" + myDouble).length() > 15) {
    formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.######E0");
    screen.setText(formatter.format(myDouble));
} else {
    formatter = new DecimalFormat("#");
    screen.setText(formatter.format(myDouble));
}
```